# read / write file of remote system in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

I got a task to make a button on web page and by clicking on that button I have to read and write a file of local system. How it can be possible.?

Can it be done in node.js or can it be possible if i make any browser app.

Kindly help.

Comment: question title - `read / write file of remote system` - question body `read and write a file of local system` ... so, while you make up your mind, neither is possible

Answer (score 0):

Your browser doesn't have permission to edit files, you can run a `javascript` in `node.js` to read and write files.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFile('package.json','utf-8');
console.log(file);
```

Comment: I went through this link https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

I want to it browser only. Can i read and write file in sandboxed area of browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can read or write files using Nodejs using `fs` module.

To write file in Node js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile(filename, data, [encoding], [callback])
```

To Read file in Node js :

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.readFile(file, [encoding], [callback]);
```